# Does bigger/wider grid better provide better user experience nowadays?

Tags: layout, grid

Does bigger/wider grid provide better user experience nowadays as 16:9 are more common?

I don't see many 960px/1000px wide layouts these times.

There is some data favouring e.g. bigger buttons, but what about whole grid/layout?

Comment: Why this question? Are you thinking of designing something for ultra wide screens and are you concerned about the results? Please give more context as it is a very vague question. It can not be answered as it depends on many things how wide a design should/could be (lets start with content alone).

Answer (score 2):

When used best, a grid is based on the most appropriate type size(s) of the typeface being used. The grid determines how many lines of text are able to fit in one row as well as how wide each body of text can be.

Within the last 10 years, larger type sizes for body text has become more common on websites in a push to improve readability (and in turn experience). Larger text can lead to larger rows and columns being required.